# Remote presentation display

Tags: debian, remote-desktop

I have two Debian machines. One is connected to a projector for a presentation, and the other is a netbook that doesn't have a working VGA output. How can I play a presentation on the netbook, but have it displayed through the projector? I need the projector laptop to connect to the netbook somehow and display the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on VNC on the machine with broken VGA output. By default it's installed as "remote connection" on Debian 7.